# process.env.NODE_ENV has two different values in config and in policies

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have built authentication middleware which I use across my Express application.
Now I'd like to use the same middleware for Sails. However, I can't access node env from it when it's used in Sails. The middleware lives under `policies/auth.js` folder:

```
var auth = require( 'tb-auth' )( {
  appName: 'test'
} );

module.exports = auth.authenticate;
```

And it's used by config/policies.js

```
module.exports.policies = {
   '*': 'auth'
}
```

Middleware code:

```
var env = (process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
var config = require( './config/' + env + '.json' );

module.exports = {...};
```

It always falls back to `dev`. I tried to access `sails.config.environment` but it throws error that `sails` is undefined. But when I access `process.env.NODE_ENV` in middleware it is `dev` even though it is "test" in Sails config files and app file.

**EDIT:** The app runs in correct environment, when I `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` in the main app file after sails lift I see `test` however at the same time it's undefined (fallbacks to `dev`) in middleware.

**EDIT2:** I just realized that `env` is equal to `dev` because `process.env.NODE_ENV` is equal to `dev` (not because `|| 'dev'`), So if I `console.log` `NODE_ENV` in any part of Sails config it is `test` but if I console.log it in `policies/auth.js` it is `dev`

**EDIT3:** app is lifted with `optimist`:

```
require('sails').lift(require('optimist').argv);
```

Comment: You can access it (otherwise you would get an error message) but `NODE_ENV` seems to be undefined.

Comment: there are no reasonable reasons for NODE_ENV to be changed in sails. Could you try setting it to whatever string just after your first console log and let us know if you still get 'dev' later in your module.

Comment: @ChristopheAugier regardless the value I assign to it, it's always `dev` in `policies` folder, and it always has correct value in `config` folder

Answer (score 0):

process.env is global you should be able to access it from anywhere in your node code. to set your `NODE_ENV` type

```
export NODE_ENV=production
sails lift
```

or

```
NODE_ENV=production sails lift
```

Then it should be accessable anywhere in your node code, since process is on the global object of node.

Comment: It runs in correct environment. When I log in `process.env.NODE_ENV` in the app it shows correct `env` but when I do the same thing in the middleware it's undefined.